# Silent install of Unity Application Block via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, unity-container

I am attempting to perform a silent install of [Unity Application Block (Unity 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn170416.aspx) but it is throwing the following error:

> Error creating process <>. Reason: The system cannot find the
>   file specified

I am using Powershell version 5.0 and the Start-Process cmdlet as follows:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Unity3\Unity3-binaries-only.exe" -ArgumentList "/q"
```

If I remove the ArgumentList I am presented with the license agreement which requires manual interaction. This defeats my goal of a silent/unattended installation. Is it possible that the Unity3.exe file doesn't allow for silent installs, or is something else occurring?

Comment: Do you maybe want to use the tag [unity3d](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/unity3d/info) instead of [unity-container](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/unity-container/info)?

Comment: No I mean the Unity Application Block

Comment: Cool. I never tried to use it with PS, and didn't see the connection.  Good luck!